# Javascript exercise that looks fine to me but its not working

Tags: javascript, arrays

The exercise is about identifying if all elements in an array are the same and return true if they are or false if they aren't. Below is the code & my logic behind writing the code.

```
function isUniform(array){
  for(var i = array.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
    if(array[i] !== array[i-1]){
        return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Basically I want to start from the end of the array with the last element and check if its equal with the second-to-last element.If they're equal, the loop will subtract 1 from the "i" variable and the "if statement" will run again. The loop will stop when i reaches -1 and thats the point where every array element was checked and the loop should end, returning true. What am I doing / thinking wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: On the last iteration, `i` will be zero ...

Comment: Of course you have to train logic but look it up just to know what the language can do XD

Comment: Change `i>=0` to `i>0`

Comment: @Pointy, undefined no?

Comment: `typeof array.find(element => element !== array[0]) === 'undefined'` would probably be simpler

Comment: Why do you need to reverse iteration order?

Comment: @Phiter I think you're thinking of `Array.prototype.every()` but I don't see how that would make things much simpler.

Comment: @Pointy that's what you get for using too much C#! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `i` becomes 0, you are comparing `arr[0]` with `arr[-1]` which is wrong. Your checking condition should be `i > 0`.

Answer (score 2):

The very last time it run, i is 0, so you're comparing array[0] with array[-1] which is incorrect. Your Boolean condition should be i > 0 so you avoid this issue:

```
function isUniform(array){
  for(var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
    if(array[i] !== array[i-1]){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `every` method for a simplified `solution`.

```
const allEqual = arr => arr.every(x => arr[0] == x));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method that checks the array for your input using `ArrayUtils`.

```
public boolean contains(final int[] array, final int key) {     
    return ArrayUtils.contains(array, key);
}
```

Traveling so can't debug, but the last iteration of `i` will be 0 in your code and stop.